# Setup PostgreSql 14.8 on Ubuntu 22.04.1 correctly

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu, installation, configuration

this question was addressed several times but none of the existing answers were working for me.

I installed PostgreSql by the following:

```
sudo apt-get install postgresql
sudo apt-get install postgresql-client
```

That's all the packages I installed. I used sudo since I was in my personal account named roland.

I know from the documentation that **PostgreSql** creates an `os` user and a `database` user called `postgres` without password.

My `pg_hba.conf` has a first line set to peer. I did not touch it I just wanted to be aware of the content.

When I run the following statement:

```
sudo -u postgres psql
```

It should work since I change the current user to the PostgreSql's default one postgres.

I got the following error back:

```
Could not change directory to "/home/roland": Permission denied
Password for user postgres: 
psql: error: connection to server on socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432" failed: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "postgres"
```

Most internet based article says that the password for `postgres` user is blank, actually it is not working. When I hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> for the password it says *password authentication failed*.

So my Question is: how can I get into `psql CLI` to create database, user roles with passwords if the only **os** and **database** users are somehow malfunctioning?

What is suspicious for me is the **Permission denied** part. I do not know which program needs permission to access my `home` root directory and how to grant it. I do not even remember whether or not it was mentioned as a step in the documentation.

Comment: `Could not change directory to "/home/roland": Permission denied` - add a `--login` flag to your sudo to fix this one (or change permissions on your home directory). For the postgresql authentication error you have edited your pg_hba.conf - the line needs to read `local   all    postgres    peer`.

Comment: I tried also this one: ```sudo -u postgres -i ``` which switched the user correctly to postgres. Then I tried to run psql and he asked me password for postgres user despite of the fact that there should not have any password. I used blank password and got different error like before: **psql: error: connection to server on socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432" failed: fe_sendauth: no password supplied**

Comment: Like I said. The authentication problem is because you have changed the pg_hba.conf file from its default

Comment: "My pg_hba.conf has a first line set to peer"  But clearly peer isn't being used, or you would not be getting that error.  Either that first line is not the one that is matching the connection, or that pg_hba file isn't even the one that is being used in the first place.

Comment: 1) Where are you running `sudo -u postgres psql`? 2) How did you install Postgres? **Add answers** as update to question.

Comment: psql wants access to your home directory in order to read the user config, like .psqlrc file and .postgresql directory.  But psql doesn't **need** access, it will normally run just fine without it.  This message is usually just a nuisance warning.  Fixing it will probably not fix the real problem.

Comment: @RichardHuxton I did not change the pg_hba.conf. I just opened it to see what is the current configuration setting for authentication. The '''local   all    postgres    peer''' settings is the default in postgres 14 settings.

Comment: @jjanes Yes, exactly. Based on the documentation: "The peer authentication method works by obtaining the client's operating system user name from the kernel and using it as the allowed database user name (with optional user name mapping). This method is only supported on local connections." I checked also that postgres is an existing os user not only. My connection was local. So in this case psql just takes the current user which is postgres and asks the password for it which is said to be blank. I got the following: psql: error: failed: fe_sendauth: no password supplied

Comment: @AdrianKlaver I updated my question to include the answers for your questions

Comment: What you did works fine, when done on a clean system.  Either your system was not clean, or you did something else than what you reported.  Maybe your system already had a database installed so the new one picked a non-default port to run on, and now you have two of them installed and are connecting to the wrong one.

Comment: @jjanes Is it possible to remove completely my current installation safely and start again the whole process?

Comment: If you have other versions also installed with apt, you could uninstall them all, then purge them.  Obviously the purge is not safe for any data you have already loaded into those existing databases.  If you have other installations done not through apt (such as by compiling from source), then it is hard to know how to undo that, without knowing exactly what was done.

Comment: @jjanes i have never had any postgres database installed on this local machine before, so there is no data loss issue. Also this database was installed through apt only. Before I uninstall it I give it a last try. I try to change the pg_hba.conf file to let me in without password locally. Then I create a user in PostgreSql with my os credentials like roland username and my os password. Then I change back the pg_hba_conf  to peer.